# Why does the principal laugh when a guy is introducing himself?

Tags: sakigake-otokojuku

In Sakigake!! Otokojuku, Heihachi Edajima picks up the phone and introduces himself. As the other guy begins to introduce himself as well, Heihachi Edajima starts giggling, as shown in the following image:

[image: Edajima Heihachi Laughing]

Is there any particular reason for why Heihachi Edajima starts laughing in this precise moment?